# Resizing image makes grid getting out from window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a grid containing an Image (with 2 rows top and bot that I will use later) and another grid containing 4 radio button.

When I resize, if the grid's height is greater than image, I have 2 whites rows around the image :

[image]

But if the height is smaller, the image is not correctly displayed and my buttons disappear :

[image]

What can I do to keep buttons on screen and add white columns right and left to see the entire image ?

There is my code :

```
<Grid Grid.Column="2">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image Grid.Row="1"
           Source="{Binding Picture}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    <Grid Grid.Row="3">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <RadioButton Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="Red" Content="Point 1" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedPointIndex, ConverterParameter=1, Converter={StaticResource IndexBooleanConverter}}" />
        <RadioButton Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Background="Green" Content="Point 2" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedPointIndex, ConverterParameter=2, Converter={StaticResource IndexBooleanConverter}}"/>
        <RadioButton Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="Blue" Content="Point 3" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedPointIndex, ConverterParameter=3, Converter={StaticResource IndexBooleanConverter}}"/>
        <RadioButton Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Background="Yellow" Content="Point 4" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedPointIndex, ConverterParameter=4, Converter={StaticResource IndexBooleanConverter}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have simple layout problem. If you want something to take guaranteed space, use `Auto`, it take precedence over stars (stars are distributing leftover space, they get nothing if there is none).

You need following layout:

```
<Grid> <!-- high level container to ensure buttons grid is visible -->
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" /> <!-- this row take precedence over first one -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" ... > <!-- image grid -->
        ...
        <Image ... /> 
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1"> <!-- buttons grid -->
        ...
        <RadioButton ... />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And demo

[image]

Comment: This is working but it have a problem with another element. I'll try to explain. I have a feature used to draw points on the image. I defined `Image_MouseDown` to get the mouse coordinates and draw the point depending on Image `Point p = e.GetPosition(Image)`. Without my 2 row before on after my Image, I got position depending on white spaces.  Concretely, if my image is 200x200 pixels in a grid with height = 400 I will have 2 whites zone with height = 100px. IF I click on point [0;0], my point will be display on the top white zone.

Answer (score 1):

For row with the image set `<RowDefinition Height="*"/>` instead of  `<RowDefinition Height="auto"/>`. If you would like to leave spaces between image and radio button, I see your additional rows, set its height to fixed size.

Explanation:
'auto' guarantee that row of the grid will has height equals to height of the child content. If you would like to affect to size content via size of the parent control dynamically, you should use 'N*', where N - number.

For instance:

```
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/> <!-- 25% of the rest of space -->
     <RowDefinition Height="2*"/> <!-- 50% of the rest of space -->
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/> <!-- 25% of the rest of space -->
     <RowDefinition Height="auto"/> <!-- As result is static value. Height equals to height that's needed to display child content -->
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: This solution is working but I always had whites spaces around my picture cause top and bot border never disappear. Is there a way to adjust picture depending on remaining space ?

Comment: Sorry, can you explain more detailed how would you like to adjust image?

Comment: I want to display my image bigger than possible (without whites zone). The other answer correspond to this behavior (but I have another problem :-()